# Maximum vector size assignment C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a hash table using direct addressing that can hold 7 digit phone numbers and names. When I set the size of the vector to 9999999, there is no error but the program is so slow and getting halted almost.

```
std::vector <long long> myNumbers (9999999);
```

OR

```
std::vector <long long> myNumbers;
myNumbers.resize (9999999)
```

Both are failing , is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: Um, I think you don't understand how vector works. Size of a vector is how many objects it can contain. You are trying to make your vector be able to contain 9'999'999 variables of type `long long`. If you don't know how many phone numbers you want to put in it, just don't resize it at the beginning. It will resize itself after you put values in it. You can store 7-digit phone number in a single `long long` variable.

Comment: Define "getting stuck". While blanking several megabytes of memory is not fast (per-se), it's not exactly slow either. Certainly not "getting stuck" slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program getting stuck is because it's trying to allocate a lot of data for you, just like the other comment said.

However, a vector is probably not the best data structure for your data. If you're storing phone numbers, that means all your data will be between 1000000 and 9999999, so if you use an array or vector, you're not utilizing all of the space you allocated. Use a map.

-- EDIT

That said, if you expect your data to be **really** dense, filling out most of the 8,999,999 possibilities, using an array might be better after all. You can utilize all the space by creating an array of size 9,000,000, and getting the insert/lookup index by subtracting 1,000,000 from the number, effectively shifting all the numbers down by 1,000,000.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `std::vector<long long>(9999999)`, it has to initialise ~10M `long long`s. Assuming each `long long` is 8 bytes long, your program has to zero out 80 MB of memory on the spot. This is not instantaneous.

Are you sure you want to use an 80 MB vector? Sounds like a `std::unordered_map` or `std::map` (depending on whether you need the keys in order) is a better data structure to use.